# c# class create parameters

Tags: c#, class

```
 public ControlCenter_v3(string st = @"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=controlcenter_v3; Integrated Security=true;")
            : base(st)
        {
            Open();
        }
```

I made ​​mistakes as in the above code block does not. but I am getting the following error when I do the way it exist?

```
public ControlCenter_v3(string st = ConnectionStrings.Default.ControlCenter_V3)
            : base(st)
        {
            Open();
        }
```

Error

> The property or indexer 'Data.Properties.ConnectionStrings.Default' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Comment: I cannot understand your question, can you improve the language please and include the error?

Comment: Error :The property or indexer 'Data.Properties.ConnectionStrings.Default' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Comment: in *that* case... what is `Data.Properties.ConnectionStrings.Default` ?

Comment: Genuinely: we can't diagnose this without more information about `Data.Properties.ConnectionStrings`; that isn't .NET framework code

Comment: ConnectionStrings.settings file

Comment: @mcxxx k; and if you F12 into `Default` to show the member, what do you see? If I create a settings instance, I get something like `public static ConnectionStrings Default { get { return defaultInstance; } }` (give or take some whitespace)

Comment: @mcxxx ???????? huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConnectionStrings.Default.ControlCenter_V3` is almost certainly not a constant. Default values for parameters can only be constants, or things like `null`.

One option is to do something like:

```
public ControlCenter_v3(string st = null)
    : base(st ?? ConnectionStrings.Default.ControlCenter_V3)
{...}
```